# How can I check my status on an American Airlines promotion?

Tags: loyalty-programs, american-airlines

I registered with an American Airlines promotion to get "elite" status if I flew certain numbers of miles before the end of the year. I assume that once I register I need to do nothing further. I have not been entering the promotion code on the various flights I have taken since then.

How can find out how I am doing under the promotion and how close I am to the threshold? The registration notification said I could find promotion details by going to the "View All" offers page on AAdvantage but it is not listed there.

Comment: To check your mileage, you need to log into your frequent flyer account and see what you have earned for the year.

Comment: If you've not been provided your frequent flier number, then you are unlikley to have been accumalating miles

Comment: https://www.aa.com/i18n/contactAA/contact-aadvantage-customer-service.jsp

Comment: If you registered for a promotion to earn elite status, you need to verify if the promotion requires earning a certain number of elite-qualifying points, which prior to 2016 are not the same as elite-qualifying miles.  When you log in to your account you will see how many elite-qualifying miles, points, and segments you have.  The promotion usually only looks at points.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if the "promotion" to which you refer is AA's frequent flier program, a form of loyalty/rewards program that most airlines offer.

AA's program is called AAdvantage. You can track your current status by [logging in to the AAdvantage site.](https://www.aa.com/login/loginAccess.do?uri=/login/loginAccess.do&previousPage=/loyalty/profile/summary&continueUrl=/loyalty/profile/summary) If you don't have the appropriate details to log in, you will have to contact their customer service.

If you have not been providing your frequent flier number when either making reservations, or checking in, then it seems unlikley that your flights this year have been tracked. Most frequent flier programs offer the ability to add missed flights to your record, on provision of suitable evidence.

If you are referring to some other promotion *in addition* to normal AAdvantage system, then I'm not sure of the details - again, contacting customer support is probably your best option. I'd expect you could still see any progress when logged in.

Comment: It sounds like a "fast track" promotion, which offers elite status for far fewer points than usually needed, if flown within a set period (often 90 days).  Your answer is still correct: logging in to one's AAdvantage account shows the cumulative points earned (as well as elite-qualifying miles and spendable miles, but this promotion is usually limited to elite-qualifying points).

Answer (score 1):

Your best course is to call the American Airlines AAdvantage Customer Service number and ask.  Your question is ambiguous as to if you registered for the standard AAdvantage program or for a "challenge" which awards elite status for flying a reduced number of elite-qualifying points (for 2015) or miles (for 2016) in a certain period of time.  If the former (standard AAdvantage program), simply logging in to the web site or iPhone/Android app will show your progress and status.  If the latter ("challenge"), only flights coded with certain airlines count for the status (typically, the flight code needs to be AA or a joint business venture partner, e.g., BA, IB, JL, and QF.  Other partners, such as CX or AS, don't count for the "challenge."